# How to close UWP App when Win32 Application is closed?

Tags: uwp

I made the Win32 Application run as follows inside the UWP application.

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

When the called Win32 Application is terminated, I also want the UWP App to be terminated as well.

I wrote the following, but after calling Win32 Application, the UWP App is terminated immediately.

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
CoreApplication.Exit();
```

Is there any good way to make the UWP app terminate after the Win32 application is terminated?

Comment: You could communicate between the processes using an app service: https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/uwp-in-2020-in-process-app-service.html

Comment: As the mm8 said, you could use App service to communicate between these two apps. If the process is closed, the AppService also will close. Therefore, the `AppServiceDisconnected` event in UWP project will be triggered, you could terminate the uwp app in this event.